# EF Core 5.0 relational from non-relational db

Tags: c#, orm, ef-fluent-api, non-relational-database, ef-core-5.0

So here is the problem.

I have an ancient db from an old COBOL software (txt file).

**What I Want**

- Relate objects listed below without original data altered.

**Background**

DB is MS-SQL. Every imported object has a unique id(Database Generated). The "Foreign Key" that actually combines objects in old COBOL software ("NonUniqueItemProperty") is not unique. (That's why I can't create a relation between tables)

**my question is, is this even possible?**

Currently I join tables on query as

```
select item.*,owner.* from Items item
INNER JOIN Ownership ownership on item.NonUniqueItemProperty=ownership.NonUniqueItemProperty
INNER JOIN Owner owner on ownership.OwnerIdNo=owner.OwnerIdNo
```

This query returns a result set with matches (item-->ownerCount)*(item-->count). Then I use linq to group them by Item.NonUniqueItemProperty and set owners foreach Item.

**Objects:**

```
    public class Item
    {
        pullic int Id {get;set;} // database generated, non-related to original data
        public string NonUniqueItemProperty {get;set;} //sadly this is the identifier
        public virtual ICollection<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Ownership
    {
        pullic int Id {get;set;} // database generated, non-related to original data
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
        public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
        public string NonUniqueItemProperty {get;set;}
        public string OwnerIdNo {get;set;}
    }
    
    public class Owner
    {
        pullic int Id {get;set;} // database generated, non-related to original data
        public virtual ICollection<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
        public string OwnerIdNo {get;set;}
    }
```

**I tried to create a relationship at fluent api as:**

```
    item.HasMany<Ownership>(i => i.Ownerships)
                .WithOne(ow => ow.Item)
                .HasPrincipalKey(i=>i.NonUniqueItemProperty)
                .HasForeignKey(ow=>ow.NonUniqueItemProperty);
```

As far as, there is no errors but navigation properties are null.

### EDIT

After this, I realize that this expression returns an Item entity with null Ownership navigation. The result set is returned what I am looking for so navigation worked for filtering Items Set!

```
var resultSet = ctx.Items.Where(
             i => i.Ownerships.Any(
                     ow => ow.Owner.OwnerIdNo=="P12345"));
```

Comment: Why do you use NonUniqueItemProprty as keys? I'd recomment to always use ID's on every object as keys. I also think that because you use FluentAPI and say 'HasMany' and 'WithOne' you already chain the objects Item and Ownership. With IDs EntityFramework will know what belongs together. I'm not sure what it does with strings as 'ID'

Comment: @JelleSchräder, as per post explains, this is not a db of my design. The actual object has an Id field generated by database but I don't use it, since it makes no sense for THE DATA that I imported from from plain text file. And I am not allowed to alter the original data.

Comment: "From cobol" phrase actually is not an exact match for "COBOL database" is it? Furthermore, the title states "relational from non-relational db", and I stated in the post that "navigation properties are null" so other properties are not null. So, database is supported. Please consider to look at this image : [link](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d4/03/85/d40385947a8b85200ea72023a7b2cef7.png)

Comment: @Hasan First, calm down and don't take it so personal. Comments are for clarifications, people here are generally with good intent. And Get is one of the most reasonable and constructive persons and experts in this area here, so be sure he *will** give you a solution if exists. But enough on this, now on the concrete subject. In general what you are asking is not possible, because if the  
 `Item.NonUniqueItemProperty` is non unique, then  `Ownership.NonUniqueItemProperty` join would possible generate more than one much, hence the logical relationship is *to many*, hence cannot be represented

Comment: ... even logically with reference navigation property. But I'm wondering how you've mapped `Item` class - as keyless entity? Or "regular" entity by tricking EFC that `Item.NonUniqueItemProperty` is a key (unique)?

Comment: @GertArnold I don't think that we are doing sth constructive with this debate. I admit that question has missing parts, but I think, that parts are not related to neither question nor the answer. (For ex: you asked for how I do it with pure sql, but I want to leave it and use ORM, and navigations. you asked for objective, I stated that it is in the title.) So you have any ans? And yet you keep insulting. Anyways, I edited the question. Even added a strange thing under EDIT title. Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Comment: @GertArnold ok. How does the last query works?  I mean, if you use navigations while filtering it works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get navigation properties by Eager Loading in explained [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

by adding `Include(i=>i.Ownership).ThenInclude(ow=>ow.Owner)` to end of the query.

But as per two field expert suggested this shouldn't work, I am not going to implement this in code, and this could not work at later versions of EF.

### EDIT

This is a true performance killer! By writing the sql-query above, it consumes 120-150 ms for TOP 150  Items, this one is 2.500-4.000 ms (`query.Take(100)`).

(Item Count     : 350K,
Ownership Count: 390K)